# Getting phone number from number containing country code too

Tags: java, android

I need to parse a given phone number to separate the country code from the actual phone number.
Is there a way through which I can achieve this?

Comment: can you post the sample JSON or data?

Comment: I'm basically getting the data from TelephonyManager when the BroadcastReceiver is activated.

Comment: i mean how does a sample number looks like and is it containing the country code every time??

Comment: Yes e.g +919999xxxxxx, without spacews

Comment: well for India the code length is always +91 but it will not be the case for other countries it may be +1(USA) or +972 (Israel) if it is India always then you can use `number.substring(3)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/)

```
String swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00"
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
  PhoneNumber swissNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(swissNumberStr, "CH");
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
  System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
String num=phoneUtil.format(swissNumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL)
```

To get Country code:(e.g. +442446681800)

you can take substring(second number) of phone number (4)

then check if this number is country code ---> done
if not take substring(second + third number) of phone number (44)

then check if this number is country code ---> done
if not take substring(second + third + fourth number) of phone number (424)

then check if this number is country code ---> done
if not use library as above ...

But How to check Country Code:

1- add this array to string.xml on your app

```
<string-array name="CountryCodes" >
<item>93,AF</item>
<item>355,AL</item>
<item>213,DZ</item>
<item>376,AD</item>
<item>244,AO</item>
<item>672,AQ</item>
<item>54,AR</item>
<item>374,AM</item>
<item>297,AW</item>
<item>61,AU</item>
<item>43,AT</item>
<item>994,AZ</item>
<item>973,BH</item>
<item>880,BD</item>
<item>375,BY</item>
<item>32,BE</item>
<item>501,BZ</item>
<item>229,BJ</item>
<item>975,BT</item>
<item>591,BO</item>
<item>387,BA</item>
<item>267,BW</item>
<item>55,BR</item>
<item>673,BN</item>
<item>359,BG</item>
<item>226,BF</item>
<item>95,MM</item>
<item>257,BI</item>
<item>855,KH</item>
<item>237,CM</item>
<item>1,CA</item>
<item>238,CV</item>
<item>236,CF</item>
<item>235,TD</item>
<item>56,CL</item>
<item>86,CN</item>
<item>61,CX</item>
<item>61,CC</item>
<item>57,CO</item>
<item>269,KM</item>
<item>242,CG</item>
<item>243,CD</item>
<item>682,CK</item>
<item>506,CR</item>
<item>385,HR</item>
<item>53,CU</item>
<item>357,CY</item>
<item>420,CZ</item>
<item>45,DK</item>
<item>253,DJ</item>
<item>670,TL</item>
<item>593,EC</item>
<item>20,EG</item>
<item>503,SV</item>
<item>240,GQ</item>
<item>291,ER</item>
<item>372,EE</item>
<item>251,ET</item>
<item>500,FK</item>
<item>298,FO</item>
<item>679,FJ</item>
<item>358,FI</item>
<item>33,FR</item>
<item>689,PF</item>
<item>241,GA</item>
<item>220,GM</item>
<item>995,GE</item>
<item>49,DE</item>
<item>233,GH</item>
<item>350,GI</item>
<item>30,GR</item>
<item>299,GL</item>
<item>502,GT</item>
<item>224,GN</item>
<item>245,GW</item>
<item>592,GY</item>
<item>509,HT</item>
<item>504,HN</item>
<item>852,HK</item>
<item>36,HU</item>
<item>91,IN</item>
<item>62,ID</item>
<item>98,IR</item>
<item>964,IQ</item>
<item>353,IE</item>
<item>44,IM</item>
<item>972,IL</item>
<item>39,IT</item>
<item>225,CI</item>
<item>81,JP</item>
<item>962,JO</item>
<item>7,KZ</item>
<item>254,KE</item>
<item>686,KI</item>
<item>965,KW</item>
<item>996,KG</item>
<item>856,LA</item>
<item>371,LV</item>
<item>961,LB</item>
<item>266,LS</item>
<item>231,LR</item>
<item>218,LY</item>
<item>423,LI</item>
<item>370,LT</item>
<item>352,LU</item>
<item>853,MO</item>
<item>389,MK</item>
<item>261,MG</item>
<item>265,MW</item>
<item>60,MY</item>
<item>960,MV</item>
<item>223,ML</item>
<item>356,MT</item>
<item>692,MH</item>
<item>222,MR</item>
<item>230,MU</item>
<item>262,YT</item>
<item>52,MX</item>
<item>691,FM</item>
<item>373,MD</item>
<item>377,MC</item>
<item>976,MN</item>
<item>382,ME</item>
<item>212,MA</item>
<item>258,MZ</item>
<item>264,NA</item>
<item>674,NR</item>
<item>977,NP</item>
<item>31,NL</item>
<item>599,AN</item>
<item>687,NC</item>
<item>64,NZ</item>
<item>505,NI</item>
<item>227,NE</item>
<item>234,NG</item>
<item>683,NU</item>
<item>850,KP</item>
<item>47,NO</item>
<item>968,OM</item>
<item>92,PK</item>
<item>680,PW</item>
<item>507,PA</item>
<item>675,PG</item>
<item>595,PY</item>
<item>51,PE</item>
<item>63,PH</item>
<item>870,PN</item>
<item>48,PL</item>
<item>351,PT</item>
<item>1,PR</item>
<item>974,QA</item>
<item>40,RO</item>
<item>7,RU</item>
<item>250,RW</item>
<item>590,BL</item>
<item>685,WS</item>
<item>378,SM</item>
<item>239,ST</item>
<item>966,SA</item>
<item>221,SN</item>
<item>381,RS</item>
<item>248,SC</item>
<item>232,SL</item>
<item>65,SG</item>
<item>421,SK</item>
<item>386,SI</item>
<item>677,SB</item>
<item>252,SO</item>
<item>27,ZA</item>
<item>82,KR</item>
<item>34,ES</item>
<item>94,LK</item>
<item>290,SH</item>
<item>508,PM</item>
<item>249,SD</item>
<item>597,SR</item>
<item>268,SZ</item>
<item>46,SE</item>
<item>41,CH</item>
<item>963,SY</item>
<item>886,TW</item>
<item>992,TJ</item>
<item>255,TZ</item>
<item>66,TH</item>
<item>228,TG</item>
<item>690,TK</item>
<item>676,TO</item>
<item>216,TN</item>
<item>90,TR</item>
<item>993,TM</item>
<item>688,TV</item>
<item>971,AE</item>
<item>256,UG</item>
<item>44,GB</item>
<item>380,UA</item>
<item>598,UY</item>
<item>1,US</item>
<item>998,UZ</item>
<item>678,VU</item>
<item>39,VA</item>
<item>58,VE</item>
<item>84,VN</item>
<item>681,WF</item>
<item>967,YE</item>
<item>260,ZM</item>
<item>263,ZW</item>
</string-array>
```

2-

```
//Num substring of phone number
static String GetCountryISO(String Num) {
            String CountryZipCode = "";
            String[] rl = thisActivity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CountryISO);
            for (int i = 0; i < rl.length; i++) {
                String[] g = rl[i].split(",");
                if (g[0].equals(Num)) {
                    CountryZipCode = g[0];
                    break;
                }
            }
            return CountryZipCode;
        }
```

Comment: Which jar file must be used? If I am not using Maven?

Comment: go to https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/downloads/list and download any version of libphonenumber.jar

Comment: but for using this you need to know the country before hand. is there any dynamic way?

Comment: I have modified my reply